# Extracting strings from multiple parentheses using regex in pandas

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract multiple strings from multiple parentheses in a pandas df and create new columns.

The below string is found in one column of the df:

```
Unfurnished 1 Bdrm 1st flr Flat. Hall. Lounge. Kitch. Bdrm. Shower rm (CT band - A). Deposit & references required. No pets. No smokers. Rent £500 p.m Entry by arr. Viewing Owner 07425 163047 or contact solicitors. Landlord reg: 305350/110/22531. (EPC band - C).
```

I have been trying to extract the CT band and EPC band data in 2 new columns (one for each set of info respectively). I have tried mutiple versions of the code and also tried to use the info from https://regex101.com/r/5XjNqh/1

Ex: the below code

```
properties['Council_tax']=properties.Description.str.extract('(\(CT[^()*&?%])',expand=False)
```

returns

```
(CT
```

Expected output:

```
| Description        | Council_tax_band | EPC_band |
|--------------------|------------------|----------|
| Above string       |        A         |     C    | 
| Example string 2   |        B         |     F    |
| Example string 3   |        C         |     D    |
```

At the same time the word *'Band'* is also found as *'band'*.

I don't believe I have a good grasp of using regex correctly here. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps make the match a bit more specific `\(((?:CT|EPC) band - [A-Z])\)` https://regex101.com/r/7X5GPp/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird that code returns the EPC band only. If I remove the |EPC it returns NaN values for some as it's case sensitive -some rows have 'Band' instead of 'band

Comment: Do you want `.str.extract(r'(?i)\(((?:CT|EPC)[^()*&?%]+)\)', expand=False)`? Please show the expected output for your sample input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've updated my question with the expected output

Comment: Ok, `df['Council_tab_band'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'(?i)\(CT\s+band\s*-\s*([^()]+)\)', expand=False)` and `df['EPC_band'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'(?i)\(EPC\s+band\s*-\s*([^()]+)\)', expand=False)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 's+band' returns NaN values for the rows that contain 'Band' due to case sensitivity. Is there any way to avoid including the word band in the search pattern in order to get full results?

Comment: `(?i)` is a case insensitive modifier - did you remove it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my bad, just reviewed the strings in questions and the NaN entries are correct as no values are present. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
df['Council_tab_band'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'(?i)\(CT\s+band\s*-\s*([^()]+)\)', expand=False)
df['EPC_band'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'(?i)\(EPC\s+band\s*-\s*([^()]+)\)', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/5q7mEe/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/5q7mEe/2)

*Regex details*

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `EPC` - a string
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `band` - a word `band`
- `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with whitespaces
- `([^()]+)` - Group 1: any 1 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Sorry to come back on this. Followed the above logic to extract the word `Lounge` from the string and used this : `r '|(^\s*Lounge$\))'` but it's not being recognised. What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: @Alex03 You did not follow the above logic, it is some other logic. Why extract a known word? If you need to check if a string contains the word `Lounge` at the end of string, you would use `r'\bLounge$'`. `$` is the end of string. `$\)` in your regex requires `)` to be after the end of string - this is not possible, and your regex always fails.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is extract the word `Lounge` in order to create a new column for it in the dataframe.

Comment: @Alex03 Sorry, but it is out of the current question scope.

Comment: question posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62895211/extract-word-from-string-using-extract-and-regex-and-create-new-column-in-dat . Thank you